# Android horizontal ProgressBar doesn't match parent

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to use a custom `ProgressBar` using PNG images for the background and progress. I want something that looks like this :

[image: How it should look]

But instead, I have this:

[image: How it looks]

Here is my background image:

[image: ProgressBar]

I would like my ***background*** to **fit the screen**, but it doesn't. I can only see a part of my `ProgressBar`. However, if I set `android:indeterminate="true"` in my XML layout, the background fits the screen (like in the first image), but I don't want an indeterminate `ProgressBar`.

**Here is my layout** :

```xml
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBarInventory"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"
    android:max="10000"
    android:progress="0"/>
```

**custom_progress_bar.xml** :

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_back"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar_front"/>

</layer-list>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: This works for `ImageView`, but my background and progress images are `Item`

Answer (score 0):

How about setting `ProgressBar` width programmatically with

```
// get your device's width.
float deviceScreenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Comment: My `ProgressBar` is cropped when I set a width. I'd like it to fit the screen instead of being cropped.